# Angular 2 : ready for production ? and browser support

Tags: angular

I have two questions on angular 2 :

1 - Does somebody know what's the current browser support for Angular 2 rc ? 
I don't find a clear answer.

2- Is it a good plan to use Angular 2 for a new enterprise project ? We have to make a choice for a big web app and i wonder if i shouldn't use angular 1.5 and migrate in few months

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. There's compatibility widget at [github/angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/); You can also find details here: https://saucelabs.com/u/angular2-ci. This info is for current build, but I believe the goal is for all boxes to be green.
2. I'd suggest you identify core features of your app, and then check if there are any blocking issues with Angular2. How soon you need the app? Maybe final will be released by the time you finish (: You can start with v2, and if you run into something you can't handle, look into `ng-upgrade` and mixing v1.5 and v2 code...

Comment: Safari is currently excluded because of network issues with the test infrastructure https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9252

Comment: seems to ok on safari : "Safari 8. 9.0 and 9.1 are supported: https://travis-ci.org/angular/angular/jobs/138100724#L1022"

Comment: 2. @sasxa, it's seems to be a good plan. I did'nt know about ng-upgrade to mix V1.5 and V2. the app is expected in october in production... I hope that the final ng2 release will be annouced in July, is it realist ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that starting something now with the plan to migrate in a few months might not be the best idea.

I would further state that the breaking changes have slowed to a trickle and it's probably ready to start going into wider use. Ng2 might actually be 'done' in a few months as well. 
However, documentation is extremely spotty and inconsistent/wrong... so development in ng2 might be slower than simply working in ng1 and coming into the ng2 fold once things settled down a bit.

Comment: thx for reply. I quickly read the documentation and so im surprising about your opinion : "documentation is extremely spotty and inconsistent/wrong". Why do say that ?

Comment: It is new (so there isn't a lot of stuff for it from 3rd parties) and its' changing enough that the 3rd party documentation is often out-of-date.  Even the official docs lack a bit... You don't really notice this until you start digging in.
For example, only chapters 1-4 (of 9) are done here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html
And you'll notice the "not yet documented" a lot in the API docs, for example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZoneError-class.html

It's not that you generally can't figure it out, it's just that stuff isn't "easy" yet.